# Use Regex to match a set of numbers with variable positioning?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to use RegEx to match a set of numbers inputed by users. I want the user to supply the positions and values of 4 digits. The idea is to take this info, search a list and return a 'matching numerical string' of 10 digits if and only if the digits supplied by the user are in the right position. Can anyone provide a regular expression that I can use? I'm at my wits end and trying not to get fired.

Quick update with an example: User inputs ##2#5#8##9

should match

1528578009
8324598769

shouldnt match

4726754839
5023859800

Hope this helps to give an idea of what Im trying to do. Thanks for the responses

Comment: Could you add some examples of what users will input, what data will be searched, and what you expect to be returned?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated the question as you suggested. @Lithis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand your input is :

p1 v1

p2 v2

p3 v3

p4 v4

where p is the position and v is the value of the digit.
Now if that is the case, arrange them in increasing order of position so i would assume p1 < p2 < p3 < p4.

Now calculate the following values :

a1 = p1 - 1

a2 = p2 - p1 - 1

a3 = p3 - p2 - 1

a4 = p4 - p3 - 1

a5 = 10 - p4

Now use the following regex

```
[1-9]{a1}v1[0-9]{a2}v2[0-9]{a3}v3[0-9]{a4}v4[0-9]{a5}
```

The method is based on the fact that position is 1 based. That is the most  significant digit's position is considered as 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like

```
0123456789
0103050709
0020406080
0123000000
```

you can use a regular expression like `^0123......$` to match any string with "0123" as the first four digits, matching the first and last line. Likewise, `^.1.3.5.7..$` will match any string with 1, 3, 5, and 7 in positions 2, 4, 6, and 8, matching the first two lines.

Given user input of pairs of integers *d* and *p* that indicate a digit and a position, you can easily generate such a regular expression string. One simple method would be to start with the string `"^..........$"` and replace each character at index *p* with the character *d* (if the index is one-based. Add one to *p* if the index is zero-based). Make sure *d* is only a single digit, and that *p* is within the proper bounds.

If you want to be a more strict with your regular expression, use `\d` instead of `.` to match digits instead of any character.